# Setting up a web project (ASP.NET Core 3) to be both client and ApiResource for IdentityServer

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I know this is absurd, and highly stupid to do, but how does your Startup.cs (for the client + Api Resource project) have to look, if you want to be both a `Client` towards the IdentityServer, and an `ApiResource`, using reference tokens?

The idea I had is the following: Require users to authenticate using OpenID Connect. Store credentials in cookies, but after that instead of relying on them, proceed to do what a normal ApiResource does with a reference token -> hit introspect endpoint, check if the token (grabbed from the cookie) is valid, if so -> allow access, if not -> revert to authentication.

Sadly I can't make the above behavior work at all. I'm not sure which schema goes where, especially the cookies one. If I set it as the default schema, authorization passes, but if the token is rejected, I still have access to the resources, because the API still looks at the cookie as a reference to the token, when in reality the token has already been revoked. (Introspect will return false)

I don't need any configuration pointers for the project hosting the Identity Server.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this is by using the Implicit grant type ,like this :

```
    new Client
                    {
                        ClientId = "Client_implicit",
                        ClientSecrets = new [] { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },
                        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Implicit,
                        AllowedScopes = new [] {
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                            IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                        },
                        AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true,
                        RedirectUris = new [] { "...Api Adress .../signin-oidc" },
                        PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "...Api Adress ../signout-callback-oidc" },
                    }
```

On Api startup class  :

```
  services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
   .AddCookie()
   .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
   {
       options.SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       options.Authority = "...IdentityServer Adress";
       options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
       options.ClientId = "Client_Implicit";
       options.ClientSecret = "secret";
       options.ResponseType = "id_token token";
       options.Scope.Add("profile");
       options.Scope.Add("openid");
       options.GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true;
       options.SaveTokens = true;
   });
```

And on your case you don't need to Api resource as your client is the Api resource also

for sign out create an action on your api for logout contain this :

```
 await HttpContext.SignoutAsync("Cookie");
 await HttpContext.SignoutAsync("OpenIdConnect");
```

so the senario for login will be like this :

- the user will try to log in
- the api will redirect the use to IdentityServer
- IdentityServer will check user credentials and if success will
  redirect to the api with (access_token)
- the user now loggedIn

the senario for logout:

- the user will call logout;
- access_token will erase from cookie and from IdentitySever

Comment: My idea is exactly that - to have the app registered **as an ApiResource** in the identity server project, **as well as a Client**. Furthermore, to make things even more nastier, it has to work with **reference tokens** (not self-contained JWT's).

What you're showing is just a normal **Client** setup.